# What's the meaning of "spinning" in "spinning fairy tales"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The context is: "Santato wasn't spinning fairy tales.".

It means "fantasy"?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10):

Here's my totally off-the-top-of-my-head, unresearched answer: "Spinning" a fairy tale basically means to tell a story you are making up as you go along. I believe this comes from the fact that the word "yarn" is sometimes used as a colloquialism for "fictional story". Yarn is made through a process called spinning, and so when you are telling a story you are "spinning a yarn". I think the verb "spinning" has oozed out of that construction and is sometimes now used on its own to refer to the telling of a story.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I thought "spinning" is a "adj". After reading your lines, I think it's in the form of "was not doing" .

Comment: @Lincoln - Yes, in this case, "spinning" is a verb. See [Macmillian Def. #6](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/spin): _to tell a story, especially one that is not true, in an interesting and exciting way_. So, "Santato wasn't spinning fairy tales" means, "Santato was telling the truth!"

Comment: Thank you! @J.R. I forget the name of Macmillian Dictionary, and just check the Oxford dictionary...

Comment: @Lincoln - Don't forget about [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=spin); that will hook you up with Oxford **and** Macmillan – and a dozen or so more good dictionaries, too!

Answer (score 3):

From The Free Dictionary, [*spin*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spin):

> "to produce, fabricate, or evolve in a manner suggestive of spinning thread: to spin a tale."

I believe this is the meaning here. It could be restated as:

> Santato wasn't just imagining [and telling] fairy tales [but was telling the truth].

Comment: Agreed. Today "spin" is often used in relation to political "story telling" to distort what is (or was) said, or at least to emphasize what's advantageous to your side -- to put "spin" on an event or story to accrue advantage over an opponent.

Comment: I see that as a subtly different meaning. "spin" in the political sense is to twist the true story, while "spin" here is an outright fabrication.

Comment: Well, in politics you twist a true story by introducing false material, exaggerating aspects of [the true story], overemphasizing parts advantageous to you, and not mentioning/belittling/silencing discussion of parts disadvantageous to you. There are still falsehoods involved.